# Creating a variable-sized array without malloc

Tags: c

I'm writing a program in C which I want to read an array length, and create an array of that size. However, C does not support variable-lengthed arrays, so I was wondering how I could do this. I do not want to change my compiler settings.

I was thinking about somehow using preprocessor directive to my advantage, but I have not been able to do so. Pretty much, I have an integer variable containing my desired size, and I would like to declare the array with 0's. Also, I do not want to use malloc/other dynamic array methods.

This might seem basic, but I have been struggling to do this for some time. If it matters, I am receiving the array size through I/O.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify - I want to do this without malloc

Comment: You can't do it without malloc. Either you define a size compile time or allocate memory runtime.

Comment: I am receiving the integer through I/O. Does that matter?

Comment: No - if you don't know the size until runtime, `malloc` or one of its ilk is your only way of dynamic allocation.

Comment: BTW: C does support VLAs (just C++ doesn't)...

Comment: (1) C *does* support variable length arrays, so you could use them, or (2) The only other alternative is to use one of the `malloc` functions (or write your own, which would be pointless and have portability problems).

Comment: VLAs are evil. They are just a syntax wrapper for alloca() or malloc(), but with less control. The consensus here is right--if you don't know the size of the array until runtime, you need malloc() (or one of its brethren). No way around it.

Comment: C90 didn't support VLAs. C99 did. C11 made them optional.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: There is just as much control for VLAs as there is for constant-length arrays. If you need to store up to 1000 elements, defining a VLA with a size you guarantee to be <= 1000 is just as safe as defining the array with a fixed size of 1000. (Unless you have a C11 compiler that chooses not to support them for some reason.)

Comment: As everybody said, you have two options. Using malloc, or having a fixed sized array. Why you don't want to use malloc?

Comment: @KeithThompson so how do I check for allocation failure with a VLA and run alternate code?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: You don't. How do you check for allocation failure with a fixed-length array? For that matter, you can check for `malloc` failure, but that's not always reliable (see the OOM killer on Linux).

Comment: That was my point: you have more control using malloc/alloca. There's never any good reason to use VLAs. (Though you are correct that malloc and large fixed arrays are not without issues of their own).

Comment: What kind of system? The correct answers are wildly different between PC and an embedded system.

Comment: This was an interview question that I got. So it could have been a challenge question, I guess? The interviewer said explicitly not to use dynamic memory allocation (e.g. malloc). Also, they did not want "variable-lengthed arrays are a part of C99" as an answer

Answer (score 4):

There are several possible solutions, none of which satisfy all of your requirements.

A call to `malloc` is the obvious solution; that's what it's for. You've said you don't want to use `malloc`, but you haven't explained why.

C does support variable-length arrays -- more or less. VLAs did not exist in C90, were introduced in C99, and were made optional in C11. So if you want portable code, you can't assume that they're supported. If they are, you can do something like this:

```
int size;
// get value of size from input
int vla[size];
```

There are some restrictions. If there isn't enough memory (stack size can be more restrictive than heap size), the behavior is undefined. On the other hand, the same is true for ordinary fixed-size arrays, and VLAs can let you allocate a smaller amount of memory rather than assuming a fixed upper bound. VLAs exist only at block scope, so the object will cease to exist when control leaves the enclosing block (typically when the function returns).

You could define an array (probably at file scope, outside any function definition) that you know is big enough for your data. You'll have to specify some upper bound. For example, you can define `int arr[10000];` and then reject any input bigger than 10,000. You could then use an initial subset of that array for your data.

You say you want to create a "variably-sized array", but you "do not want to use malloc/other dynamic array methods". It sounds like you want to create a dynamic array, but you don't want to create a dynamic array. It's like saying you want to drive a screw, but you don't want to use a screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

> However, C does not support variable-lengthed arrays,

Wrong. This is perfectly valid C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int size;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int arr[size];
}
```

It's called VLA (variable length array) and has been a part of C since 1999. However, it's optional from C11, but big compilers like clang and gcc will never remove them. At least not in the foreseeable future.

Comment: which might, under the covers, call malloc.  You can’t know that it does, doesn’t, and have no mechanism to detect failure.   In all reasonable terms, it isn’t C.

Comment: Unfortunately (1) it's a part that had to be backpedaled, becoming optional and (2) the code basically allocates as much stack as the input says, without any way of detecting a problem if that is too much.  So "perfectly valid" is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Since the array is stored on the stack it is more likely to use alloca

Comment: @mevets: It's very unlikely to use `malloc`. The lifetime ends at the end of the innermost enclosing block. VLAs are clearly intended to be allocated on the stack. An implementation could use `malloc` to allocate VLAs, but it would have to generate additional code to call `free` at the right time, regardless of how the block is exited (`goto`, `longjmp`, etc.). Incidentally, VLAs were introduced in C99 and made optional in C11.

Comment: @mevets that's a spurious objection, you could make the same argument about any language construct.

Comment: It is not spurious at all.  The authors of C made very sure that the language itself contained no “surprises” -- no searches, allocations or anything of the sort.   The language committee, free of any accountability, made a terrible choice to introduce a facility that made no sense with respect to the nature or intent of the language.   Further, they enabled future ones to continue the tradition of bad decisions, up to and including the inane definition of atomics.   Spurious; no.   They are incompetent, and should be stripped.

Comment: @KeithThompson  -- should use alloca?   What if N is 1 000 000 ? or 1 000 000 000?   Oh, right, it could report it by having the VLA be null.   Try checking whether your VLA can be NULL.   So, now you have a C construct which can cause your program to fault, with no way for you to intercept, recover or avoid it.   Does that really sound like C?

Comment: @mevets: `alloca` is non-standard and not portable. If `alloca` fails due to stack overflow, the behavior is undefined; it does not report failure by returning a null pointer. A VLA cannot be null. A VLA is an array. Only pointers can be null. Arrays are not pointers. If VLA allocation fails due to stack overflow, the behavior is undefined. Of course exactly the same is true for fixed-length arrays. Stack space is typically more limited than heap space, so neither VLAs nor `alloca` are suitable for very large objects.

Comment: @mevets: `void func(void) { char big_array[1000000]; /* ... */ }` -- There's a C construct that can cause your program to fault, with no way for you to intercept, recover, or avoid it. Yes, that sounds like C.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask: why are you allergic to malloc()?

The reason I ask is that many attempts to define a *safe profile* for C propose that malloc is the source of all evil.   In that case:

```
int *arr;
arr = mmap(0, sizeof *arr * N, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is read the array length, and then generate the source code of a program:

```
fprintf(outfile, "int main(void) { static int arr[%d]; ...}\n", size);
```

Then execute the compiler on the generated program (e.g. using the `system` function), and run the resulting executable.

Comment: You're assuming a compiler is available on the target system.

Answer (score 0):

Any language which supports variable length arrays uses dynamic memory allocation mechanism underneath to implement the functionality. 'C' does not have a syntactic sugar which supports true variable length arrays, but it provides all the mechanics needed to mimic one.

`malloc`, `realloc`, `free`, and others can easily be used to handle dynamic allocations and deallocations for arrays of any size and types of elements. You can allocate data in memory and use a pointer to return the reference to caller functions or pass to other functions. ('C' VLAs on the other hand are of limited use and cannot be returned to the caller if allocated on stack).

So, your best option (unless you are in embedded software development) is to start using 'c' dynamic memory allocation.